# VSTS Create new WorkItem

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using the VSTS REST API and I'm trying to create a new WorkItem. But I'm only able to get an existing WorkItem from VSTS and update the WorkItem.

```
        var listDoNotUpdate = new List<string>();
        listDoNotUpdate.Add("System.BoardColumn");
        listDoNotUpdate.Add("System.BoardColumnDone");
        var wi = await this.Client.GetWorkItemAsync(4000);
        wi.Fields["System.Title"] = "Test";
        wi.Fields["System.Description"] = "Test";
        wi.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria"] = "Test";
        var doc = new JsonPatchDocument();
        foreach (var field in wi.Fields)
        {
            if (!listDoNotUpdate.Contains(field.Key))
            {
                doc.Add(new JsonPatchOperation
                {
                    Operation = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Operation.Replace,
                    Path = string.Concat("/fields/", field.Key),
                    Value = field.Value
                });
            }
        }

        await this.Client.UpdateWorkItemAsync(doc, 4000);
```

But how can I create a new WorkItem and upload this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close.  Instead of calling UpdateWorkItemAsync you need to call UpdateWorkItemTemplateAsync.

```
var collectionUri = "https://{account}.visualstudio.com";
var teamProjectName = "{project}";
var workItemType = "{workItemType}";
var client = new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(new Uri(collectionUri), new VssClientCredentials());

var document = new JsonPatchDocument();
document.Add(
    new JsonPatchOperation()
    {
        Path = "/fields/System.Title",
        Operation = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Operation.Add,
        Value = "Title"
    });

var wi = client.UpdateWorkItemTemplateAsync(
    document,
    teamProjectName,
    workItemType).Result;
```

Comment: It's a case of poorly-named methods for sure, but yes [the doc](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/work-items) shows that "create work item" is a PATCH against the WorkItemType in Project scope, which appears to be mapped to UpdateWorkItemTemplateAsync().

Comment: Method 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.WorkItemTrackingHttpClientBase.UpdateWorkItemTemplateAsync' is obsolete: 'Use CreateWorkItem instead'

Answer (score 4):

It seems they forgot the CreateWorkItemAsync method. All other Update methods have a corresponding Create method.
To create a work item anyway, you could use the following snippet

```
var client = new RestClient(string.Format(
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    "https://{0}.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/{1}/_apis/",
    "<vstsAccount>",
    "<project>"));
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("accessToken", "<accessToken>");
var json = @"[{'op': 'add','path': '/fields/System.Title','value': 'Title of your work item'}]";
var request = new RestRequest("wit/workitems/$Product Backlog Item?api-version=1.0", Method.PATCH);
request.AddParameter("application/json-patch+json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

The response will contain the json of the new work item. Use it to extract the id of the new item.

Comment: `CreateWorkItemAsync()` is available in the pre-release version of the .NET client for the REST API. As of 1/27/16, that's version 14.92.1-preview. So: `Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client -Pre`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the "Add" operation instead of the "Replace"?

See also https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/work-items#Createaworkitem

Comment: Yes, I tried to use the "Add" Operation, but no new WorkItem was created in VSTS.

Answer (score 1):

As of v16.135.0 at least (possibly earlier), there is a CreateWorkItemAsync on the WorkItemTrackingHttpClient object.

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     [Preview API] Creates a single work item.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   document:
    //     The JSON Patch document representing the work item
    //
    //   project:
    //     Project ID
    //
    //   type:
    //     The work item type of the work item to create
    //
    //   validateOnly:
    //     Indicate if you only want to validate the changes without saving the work item
    //
    //   bypassRules:
    //     Do not enforce the work item type rules on this update
    //
    //   suppressNotifications:
    //     Do not fire any notifications for this change
    //
    //   userState:
    //
    //   cancellationToken:
    //     The cancellation token to cancel operation.
    public virtual Task<WorkItem> CreateWorkItemAsync(JsonPatchDocument document, Guid project, String type, Boolean? validateOnly = null, Boolean? bypassRules = null, Boolean? suppressNotifications = null, Object userState = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```